# using decimal.get_context().prec gives error

Tags: python, decimal

I want to calculate decimals upto 120 digits of the float value 1/919.

```
import decimal  
get_context().prec = 120
result = decimal.Decimal(1) / decimal.Decimal(919)
print(result)
```

But this gives error:

```
module 'decimal' has no attribute 'get_context'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, it simply outputs:

```
NameError: name 'get_context' is not defined
```

There are two solutions to your problem:

### Using global context

You were close enough, it was `getcontext` and not `get_context`

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 120
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(919)
Decimal('0.00108813928182807399347116430903155603917301414581066376496191512513601741022850924918389553862894450489662676822633297062')
```

### Using specific context

If you want a precision for a single operation, or have more flexibility on your context, you can create them:

```py
>>> from decimal import Context
>>> context = Context(prec=120)
>>> context.divide(1, 919)
Decimal('0.00108813928182807399347116430903155603917301414581066376496191512513601741022850924918389553862894450489662676822633297062')
```